# Change Ceiling Fan to Just Light - Controlled by 2 Separate Switches

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have found numerous solutions related to switching from a ceiling fan/light combo to just a light fixture but they all relate to having a switch that controls the light and a separate switch that controls the fan.

My situation is different in that I have two switches that both controlled the ceiling fan light. One switch at either entrance to my kitchen.

The fan/light I took down had blue wire connected to red coming out of my ceiling box, white wire connected to white from the ceiling box, and black wire connected to black from the ceiling box. Since I am now switching to a light fixture only, do I connect both red and black from the ceiling box to the black of the light fixture?

It's unclear to me as most of the answers on this forum relate to black being for light and red being for fan where as in my situation the black is from one switch controlling the fan/light and red is from another switch controlling the same fan/light.

My new light fixture only has black and white and so wondering what to do with both the black and red wires from my ceiling box?

Comment: You have a 3-way switch controlling the light and will need to wire it accordingly. There are a _bunch_ of questions here relating to 3-way switches. Any answer by "Harper" will usually have drawings showing how they're to be wired (there are several different methods), you can pick the one that matches how your wires are laid out and follow the drawings.

Answer (score 0):

The red controlled the light on your fan. That red would now connect to the black on the new light fixture.  Then white to white and ground to ground.
Cap the black wire in the ceiling box and you should be good to go with the switches controlling the new light as they did with the light on the fan.

Comment: Good answer, *except* that there is not, as far as I know, any industry standard coloring that would indicate the colors on the fan/light. So the light might have been the black wire (connected to black) or the red wire (connected to blue). A little checking of either the switch boxes or (carefully) with a multi-meter would determine which is which.

Comment: The OP stated that the fan had a blue wire connected to the red coming out of the ceiling box.  Blue is universally used to power a light in a fan/light combo.  Thus the red wire controlled the light and will control the new light as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be answered by talking about colors of the wires.

Also per your description you can control the fan and light simultaneously from two different location single switches.

That would say you have something called 3 way switch.

You need to go and get a device called "Non contact tester.

Now you need two people, one to measure at the ceiling box, the other to switch the switch.

Note which wire switches on/off as indicated by the testing device.

Choose one for your light and connect to the black from the light, and cap off the other.

Connect the neutral in the ceiling box (usually white) to the white of the light.